# I need to create dynamic multilevel menu using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I tried to create multilevel menu using codeigniter 
 these are the two functions i used to echo the menu.

```
function loop_array($array = array(), $parent_id = 0) {
    if (!empty($array[$parent_id])) {
    // echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($array[$parent_id] as $items) {
            echo '<li><a class = "parent"><span>';
            echo $items['label'];
            echo '</span></a>';
            loop_array($array, $items['id']);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

function display_menus($menu_items) {
// var_dump($menu_items);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($menu_items as $rows) {
        $array[$rows['parent']][] = $rows;
    }
    loop_array($array);
}
```

then the out put html code is like

```
<div id='Mymenu' style=' color: #000; width: 960px; background-image:url(); clear: both; text-align: center; height: 46px;'>
    <div id="menu"> 
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a class = "parent"><span>Home</span></a></li><li><a class = "parent"><span>Code</span></a><li><a class = "parent"><span>PHP</span></a><li><a class = "parent"><span>Scripts</span></a><li><a class = "parent"><span>Archive</span></a><li><a class = "parent"><span>Snippet</span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a class = "parent"><span>Help</span></a></li></ul></li><li><a class = "parent"><span>CSS</span></a></li></ul></li><li><a class = "parent"><span>Contact</span></a></li></ul>        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

but i need to make this as

```
<div id='Mymenu' style=' color: #000; width: 960px; background-image:url(); clear: both; text-align: center; height: 46px;'>
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index" class="parent"><span>HOME</span></a>
            <div><ul>
                <li><a href=""><span>Vertical Menu</span></a>
                <li><a href=""><span>Slide show</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="news"><span>NEWS</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>ACADEMICS</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>PROGRAMME</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>ADMISSIONS</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="courses"><span>COURSES</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="contact_us"><span>CONTACT US</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="feedback"><span>Feedback</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

can anyone give me a way to do this?

Comment: aren't you missing $this-> when calling those functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your target code is faulty html to begin with (not closed html tags) and I am not sure if it's really what you need or want, ie is it really the ultimate correct form?

Further if you formulate your problem clearly and have the code in a readable format (instead of on one line) others don't have waste time to understand what you want in the first place.

I assume you have a tree-like / multilevel menu which you want to print out differentiating between internal nodes (ie nodes with children, or "parents") and terminal nodes (ie your "last" elements).

Your *display_menus* function groups the menu items by its parent menu id, and seems correct.

Your *loop_array* function seems to be almost there:

```
function loop_array($array = array(), $parent_id = 0)
{
    if (!empty($array[$parent_id]))
    {
        echo "\n<ul>";
        foreach ($array[$parent_id] as $items)
        {
            // is it a terminal node?
            if (empty($array[$items['id']]))
            {
                $class = 'last';
            }
            else
            {
                $class = 'parent';
            }

            // is there a link?
            if (empty($items['my-link-field']))
            {
                $link = '#';
            }
            else
            {
                $link = $items['my-link-field'];
            }

            // if you do not divide your output string into several statements,
            // the code becomes more readable
            // I mean
            // it
            //                            feels 
            //         like
            //                   several
            //  fragments
            //          that
            //                       must
            // be seen, understood and put into context. Which -in any language- is just easier with a nice flow.

            echo "<li><a class='{$class}' href='{$link}'><span>{$items['label']}</span></a>";

            loop_array($array, $items['id']);

            echo "</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

If you still do not get the desired result, I would assume your data ($menu_items) to be incorrectly set up. As you seem to have checked that already (commented var_dump), you might want to check the data passed to loop_array, ie $array.